# printing only those strings that include 2-digit number

Tags: c++

printing only those strings that include 2-digit number

the text inside "myFile.txt is

{the pink double jump 34

the rising frog 2

doing the code 11

nice 4 }
"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    
    std::string path = "myFile.txt";

    std::ifstream de;

    de.open(path);


    if (!de.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "nah";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "file is opened";


        std::string str;


        while (!de.eof()) {
            std::getline(de, str);

            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                int aa = 10;
                if (str[i] > aa) {
                    str = "0";
                }
            }
    
            std::cout << str << "\n\n";
            
        }
        
        

        }


        
    }
```

what am I doing wrong? how can I check if there is any 2-digit number inside the string?

Comment: [`std::regex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) will be useful.

Comment: Also note that your usage of ` while (!de.eof())` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `stoi` as follows:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inp("test.txt");
    std::string word;
    std::vector<std::string> listOfTwoDigitStrings;
    while(inp>>std::ws>>word) {
        if(word.length() == 2) {
            int num = std::stoi(word);
            if(num >= 10 && num <= 99) {
                listOfTwoDigitStrings.push_back(word);
            }
        }
    }
    for(const auto& word: listOfTwoDigitStrings) {
        std::cout<<word<<' ';
    }
    std::cout<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

which has the output

> 34 11

when `test.txt` contains

> {the pink double jump 34
>
> the rising frog 2
>
> doing the code 11
>
> nice 4 } "

P.S.: As you're looking for strings, just read in strings rather than lines and *then* reading off strings from that line. Reading off strings just makes it simpler since it boils down to just narrowing down to 2-digit strings and then just verifying whether they are numbers or not. Also, as mentioned in the comments, refrain from `!file.eof()` code.